# GoRouter - Can I push 2 pages at once?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes, flutter-go-router

I'm using [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) and I am about to do this in a callback of one of my buttons:

```dart
EvelatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    GoRouter.of(context)
      ..push('/page-1')
      ..push('/page-2');
  },
)
```

This is to push 2 pages in the history at once. After the user click on this button, he ends up on the page `page-2` and when he pops the page, there is `page-1`.

Is it acceptable to do that or is there any reason not to do it?
What would be those reasons and what should I do instead?

I don't think I've seen anything like that in go_router's examples.

---

For more context, here is a code snippet (or checkout https://github.com/ValentinVignal/flutter_app_stable/tree/go-router/push-twice-at-once):

When the button is pressed, I want to display the dialog page with the `page-1` in the background.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/page-0',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/page-0',
      builder: (_, __) => const Page0Screen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/page-1',
      builder: (_, __) => const Page1Screen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/dialog',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => DialogPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const DialogScreen(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}

class Page0Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page0Screen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Page 0')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            GoRouter.of(context)
              ..push('/page-1')
              ..push('/dialog');
          },
          child: const Text('Push'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1Screen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Page 1')),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Page 1'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DialogScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DialogScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Dialog'),
    );
  }
}

class DialogPage extends Page {
  const DialogPage({
    required this.child,
    super.key,
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return DialogRoute(
      settings: this,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return child;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ##### `go_router` doesn't support pushing two `routes` at the same time. And it is not a good practice to `push` 2 `pages` at the same time.

##### What can you do instead?

1. You can transition from `page1` to `page2`
2. Go to `dialog page` in the `init` method of the `page2` using `context.go('/dialog');`
3. On exiting `dialog page` you can use `context.pop()` which will land you in `page1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to display a dialog you can use the showDialog function in flutter.

Below is a sample

```
showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Basic dialog title'),
          content: const Text('A dialog is a type of modal window that\n'
              'appears in front of app content to\n'
              'provide critical information, or prompt\n'
              'for a decision to be made.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
              ),
              child: const Text('Disable'),
              onPressed: () {
                GoRouter.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
              ),
              child: const Text('Enable'),
              onPressed: () {
                GoRouter.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```